# C++: Opening a url in default browser on Windows without admin privileges

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am stuck at a point where my app needs to open a url in default browser, but it doesn't need to have admin rights and I dont want to give a UAC pop up.

I tried    `ShellExecute(NULL,L"open", L"http://www.google.com", 0, 0 , SW_SHOWNORMAL );`

It works well when app is having admin privileges but without them, it fails.

What are other ways I can open a url in user's default browser( without admin privileges) using C++ on Windows?

Comment: That ShellExecute call does not require admin privileges. I use very similar code in many applications that are run by non-administrator users with no issue. I leave out the verb when I want the default action (which in the case of a URL is "open"), because some document types don't register "open"; recent versions of Acrobat Reader, for instance, register "open with Acrobat ReaderX", so using "open" fails when trying to open a PDF file.

Comment: Really? Because when I run my code as admin it works . Otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: @smilepleeeaz, This code, with an include and a main function, works fine on Windows 8.1. For good measure, I tested it on the Guest account as well.

Comment: No, not really. I went to all that trouble to type that text just to lie to you. :-) Yes, really. Did you try 1) removing the verb, as I mentioned, and 2) checking the return value of the ShellExecute call to see why it failed?

Comment: Lol. Ok. I believe you. But it seems not to like my Windows 7 OS and I am clueless why? Below is my console application code.
`#include <Windows.h>

void main()
{

ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, L"http://www.google.com", 0, 0 , SW_SHOWNORMAL );
}`

Yes I have tried all the p&c of ShellExecute. And its shamelessly returning true.

Comment: Well, for starters, it's `int main`. And as said, check the return value.

Comment: @smilepleeeaz, If it's returning `true`, that's a bad thing (since `true`, nor `1`, is in the listed values). If it's returning something that you converted to `true`, it could be good or bad. See the documentation.

Comment: Do you have your web browser set to run as admin or something weird?

Comment: @chris Ok. Its returning this HINSTANCE 0x0000002a . How bad is it?

Comment: 0x2A is 42.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) says: "If the function succeeds, it returns a value **greater than 32**".  So clearly the function is succeeding as far as the OS is concerned, even if it is not behaving the way you expect.

Comment: So the function is succeeding but its not launching the url. GetLastError() is also giving 0. And my browser is not set to run as admin or anything weird. :(

Comment: Is your browser already running when you try this? If so, try shutting it down completely first.

Comment: OKAY! I closed my chrome browser. Repeated the exercise and Voila it worked. And now working like butter in every case. Damn!